# When to use C++ pointers in game development

Tags: c++, pointers

I've looked at a bunch of articles, and most tell the same story: don't use pointers unless you have to.  Coming from a C#/Java background where memory is all managed, I have absolutely no idea when it's appropriate to use a pointer, except for these situations:

- dynamic memory (like variable-size arrays)
- polymorphism

When else would I use pointers, especially in the context of gamedev?

Comment: If you're creating a game for the first time, in a language you're not familiar with, I wouldn't worry about the performance of pointers.

Comment: It's not a question about performance, but I don't want to make any bad habits right from the get-go, do you know what I mean?

Comment: Smart pointers. Smart pointers, everywhere. Not using them is one of the worst habits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"Don't use pointers, they're slow"* **doesn't make sense** (at least not in C++).

It's exactly like saying, *"Don't use variables, they're slow"*.

- Did you mean, "Don't use *dynamic memory allocation*"?
  If so:  I don't think you should worry about it right now. Write the code first, then optimize later.
- Or did you mean to say, "Don't use *raw* pointers (i.e. of type `foo*`)", which would require `new` and `delete`?
  If so, that is **good advice**: You generally want *smart pointers* instead, like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, to manage objects, instead of dealing with raw pointers. You shouldn't need to use `new` and `delete` in most C++ code, even though that might seem natural.
  But they're still pointers under the hood!
- Or did you mean something else?

### Addendum

Thanks to the @bames53 below for pointing this out:

*If passing a copy is an option* (i.e. when you're passing **small** amounts of data, not a huge structure or an array that could be larger than a few registers, e.g. on the order of ~16 bytes), do *not* use pointers (or references) to pass data; pass by copy instead. It allows the compiler to optimize better that way.

Comment: I think I understand now.  I should only use pointers when I have to, and I should use "smart pointers".

Comment: @Boreal: Yes. In general, if you're not sure what to use, use a `shared_ptr<T>` (in [C++11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982026.aspx), and also in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)) to store pointers to a dynamically allocated object. You can pass around, assign, or make copies of the pointer freely, and the object will be deleted when there are no more references to it. You will never need to call `delete` this way, and it will be safe from exception handing and whatnot as well.

Comment: Actually pointers can make code slower if your compiler is conservative and doesn't assume that the program obeys strict aliasing rules. In that case using pointers disables many optimizations.

Comment: @bames53: Could you provide example code to illustrate your point?

Comment: So shared_ptr basically has a garbage collector?

Comment: The wikipedia page has some examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)#Conflicts_with_optimization

Comment: @Boreal: No, it most certainly does not!! It is reference-counted and deterministic, unlike a garbage collector (which is not reference-counted and non-deterministic).

Comment: @bames53: That's just a description, not example C++ **code**... my point is compilers nowadays are pretty smart, so I don't expect that to be an issue in most cases, so it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: The compiler being smart doesn't make the issue go away. If the compiler can't take advantage of strict aliasing rules then in order to generate code it has to be conservative. Maybe sometimes a compiler could inline a function and do some analysis to determine that things don't alias, but it can't do that when generating, e.g., a function with external linkage. The wikipedia article links to some actual code. I don't have anything else off hand I can give you to run on your own compiler.

Comment: @bames53: Like I said: A piece of code demonstrating the significance of problem would go a long way toward making your point. :)

Comment: I went ahead and did the example shown in the 'understanding strict aliasing' article linked from wikipedia: [pastbin](http://pastebin.com/HRiyvfCM) It shows a `movzwl` instruction moved inside the loop = slower code.

Comment: @bames53: How much slower was it? (Also, which compiler?)

Comment: As much slower as I care to make it since I can cause an arbitrary number of instructions to be put into the loop with no-strict-aliasing for a constant number outside the loop with strict-aliasing. [This](http://pastebin.com/tmsVHq1W) program is ~100% slower with strict aliasing disabled. Compiler is clang trunk.

Comment: @bames53: I admit this is a huge difference (tested in MSVC, it's a 10x difference), but I should also say that not only is it a little unrealistic, it's also pretty trivial to resolve: Step (1) figure out the bottleneck, and Step (2) use `__forceinline` (if possible) or `__restrict` (if not). Both are easy to apply, and the latter is guaranteed to work. But I still don't see what this has to do with your point: how would you do this *without* pointers? Pass a vector/array instead?

Comment: Oh, and the slowdown is even more dramatics if instead of comparing -fstrict-aliasing vs. -fno-strict-aliasing, I compare using pointers vs. not using pointers, even when strict aliasing is enabled. [this](http://pastebin.com/rq53cv9X) seems to be about about 1200% slower with strict aliasing enabled, about 2500% slower with strict aliasing disabled.

Comment: @bames53: I don't know about clang (I don't have it), but in MSVC, it's actually not *quite* the aliasing that causes this, but the lack of inlining: for some reason, without `__restrict`, the function doesn't get inlined, whereas it *does* get inlined with `__restrict`. But when I use `__declspec(noinline)` along with `__restrict`, it's just as slow as before. Nevertheless, your point is well-taken: I'll edit my response, thanks. :)

Comment: It sounds like whatever inlining it's doing is being disabled because the compiler on its own can't prove that it's safe to do that when the pointers can alias. So if you tell it there's no aliasing, the optimization is enabled. If you tell it the pointers don't alias, then manually disable the optimization, it's just as slow as before.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that you don't want to have memory leaks, nor slow down the program while retrieving memory, so, if you pre-allocate the structures you will need, then you can use pointers to pass the structures around, as that will be faster than copying structures.

I think you are just confused as to why pointers may be considered bad, as there are many places to use them, you just need to think about why you are doing it.

Comment: So should I only use pointers where I cannot use references or "regular" variables?

Answer (score 3):

One primary use of pointers (although **references** are generally better when possible), is to be able to pass an object around without *copying* it. If an object contains a lot of data, copying it could be quite expensive and unnecessary. In terms of game development, you can store pointers in a container like a `std::vector` so you can manage objects in a game. For instance, you could have a vector that contains pointers to all enemies in the game so you can perform some "mass procedure" on them. It might be worthwhile to look into **smart pointers**, too, since these could make your life a lot easier (they help a great deal when it comes to preventing memory leaks).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need pointers for variable size arrays, you can (and usually should) use `std::vector` instead. You don't need raw pointers for polymorphism either; virtual functions work with smart pointers like `unique_ptr`.

In modern C++ you rarely need pointers. Often they will be hidden away inside resource owning classes like vectors. To pass objects around without copying them you can use references instead. Most of the remaining uses of pointers are covered by smart pointers. Very rarely you will want a 'non-owning' pointer, in which case raw pointers are fine.

You'll learn the appropriate uses of pointers if you learn about the things to should use instead of pointers. So learn about RAII, references, and smart_pointers.